# Trying to create nested ScriptableObject: "AddAssetToSameFile failed because the other asset is not persistent"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor, unity3d-editor

**Goal:** Create nested scriptable objects from the project view.

**Expected:** When an instance of the *container* scriptable object is created from the project view, an instance of the *child* scriptable object is created and attached to the container asset. The container should also keep a reference of the child.

**Actual:** When I try to attach the child to the container asset, it fails. I use the `AssetDatabase.AddObjectToAsset` but gives me the following error messages:

- UnityException: Adding asset to object  failed.
- AddAssetToSameFile failed because the other asset is not persistent

**Observations:** The container is created successfully. No child asset is created. The inspector shows a child reference as soon as the asset is created, but says `Type mismatch` when the name of the container is entered.

The child object is not persistent. I do not know what *persistent* means in this context. I think this might be the reason I don't understand this problem.

Following is the code of a simplified version of what I am trying to implement. The same error is reproduced.

**Container class**

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class Container : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] private Child child;
        
    private void Reset()
    {
        // Create new child
        child = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Child>();

        // Attach child to the container
        AssetDatabase.AddObjectToAsset(child, this); // This line throws exception!

        // Save changes
        AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
    }
}
```

**Child class**

```
public class Child : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] public string myString;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that until you entered the name the new created scriptableObject is not persistent yet. If you hit Escape then it is never created ;)

What you can do is **delay** the child creation until the asset was actually created. In order to check this you can use [`AssetDatabase.Contains`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.Contains.html)

Note though: I would suggest to not only rely on `Reset` but additionally use `OnValidate` and `Awake` in order to also force the child to be set when someone changes it via the Inspector. In that case I would simply check if a child already exists within this asset in order to not recreate it.

Also note: `UnityEditor` is completely stripped of in a build!

=> If this is meant to be used for runtime applications outside of the Unity Editor itself, make sure to wrap anything related to `UnityEditor` in pre-processor tags

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
any code related to UnityEditor namespace
#endif
```

so I would do something like e.g.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif

[CreateAssetMenu]
public class Container : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Child child;

    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    private void Awake()
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        EditorApplication.update -= DelayedInit;
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        // If child is already set -> nothing to do
        if (child)
        {
            return;
        }

        // If this asset already exists initialize immediately
        if (AssetDatabase.Contains(this))
        {
            DelayedInit();
        }
        // otherwise attach a callback to the editor update to re-check repeatedly until it exists
        // this means it is currently being created an the name has not been confirmed yet
        else
        {
            EditorApplication.update -= DelayedInit;
            EditorApplication.update += DelayedInit;
        }
    }

    private void DelayedInit()
    {
        // if this asset dos still not exist do nothing
        // this means it is currently being created and the name not confirmed yet
        if (!AssetDatabase.Contains(this))
        {
            return;
        }

        // as soon as the asset exists remove the callback as we don't need it anymore
        EditorApplication.update -= DelayedInit;

        // first try to find existing child within all assets contained in this asset
        var assets = AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(this));
        // you could as well use a loop but this Linq query is a shortcut for finding the first sub asset
        // of type "Child" or "null" if there was none
        child = assets.FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetType() == typeof(Child)) as Child;

        // did we find a child ?
        if (!child)
        {
            // If not create a new child
            child = CreateInstance<Child>();
            // just for convenience I'd always give assets a meaningful name
            child.name = name + "_Child";
            
            // Attach child to the container
            AssetDatabase.AddObjectToAsset(child, this);
        }
        
        // Mark this asset as dirty so it is correctly saved in case we just changed the "child" field
        // without using the "AddObjectToAsset" (which afaik does this automatically)
        EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);

        // Save all changes
        AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
    }
    #endif
}
```

Comment: It seems like this solved my original problem!

Comment: However, I do get a warning that I do not know what means. Do you know what this is?

Importer(NativeFormatImporter) generated inconsistent result for asset(guid:11395718ac42afb48906e08bc2dd8362) "Assets/_project/Scripts/NestedSOTest/New Container 1.asset"

Answer (score 0):

In AssetPostProcessor, you have this method: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetPostprocessor.OnPostprocessAllAssets.html

It will callback when assets are created / removed / moved.